# Convert Strings as Bytes to String

Tags: python, byte

I read the first few bytes of a JPEG

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
firstTwoBytes = f.read(2)
if firstTwoBytes != '\xff\xd8':
```

firstTwoBytes iny my debugger is: bytes: b'\xff\xd8' which is correct?

So my String comparison fails.  How best to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if firstTwoBytes != b'\xff\xd8':
```

Comment: Chan Thanks. As a matter of interest is this a python 3 thing?  Is there any difference in behaviour here between python2 and python3?

Answer (score 1):

So, compare to binary not to the string:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
firstTwoBytes = f.read(2)
if firstTwoBytes != b'\xff\xd8':
```